# Uniform Convergence versus pointwise Convergence

Tags: calculus

Define $f_n:[0,1]->\mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x)=x^n$. Show that the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges for each $x \in [0,1]$ but the sequence $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Hint for a slick proof: If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly what can you say about the limit function?  What is the limit function here?

Hint for a direct proof: What is the definition of uniform convergence?  Draw some pictures and see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 5):

HINTS:

1. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ if $0\le x<1$?
2. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(1)$?
3. Even if $n$ is large, there must be values of $x<1$ such that $f_n(x)$ is close to $1$; why?
4. For $x$ as in (3), $f_n(x)$ is *not* close to $0$; why does this matter?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

[image]

Note:

- For  $N$ a fixed, positive integer: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f_N(x) =1$.
- But, for any $x\ne1$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}
     f_n(x) =0$.